# My result is returning only one value, I need collection of values

Tags: php, mysql, joomla2.5

When I am executing a query in Joomla 2.5 it’s returning only one value & not all values:

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM sd_content WHERE title LIKE '%$searchval%' OR introtext LIKE '%$searchval%'";        
$db->setQuery($sql);
$result = $db->loadObject();
```

Answer (score 2):

An easy fix. You should use [`loadObjectList()`](http://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase#loadObjectList.28.29) instead of [`loadObject()`](http://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase#loadObject.28.29):

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM sd_content WHERE title LIKE '%$searchval%' OR introtext LIKE '%$searchval%'";        
$db->setQuery($sql);
$result = $db->loadObjectList();
```

Then use `print_r` to see all of the results:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

As explained in [the Joomla documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase):

- [`loadObject()`](http://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase#loadObject.28.29) returns a PHP object from a single record in the table.
- [`loadObjectList()`](http://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase#loadObjectList.28.29) returns an indexed array of PHP objects from the table records returned by the query.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to get single column you can try using `$db->loadResultArray();` in Joomla 2.5 and `$db->loadColumn();` in Joomla 3.0.